# Using selenium simultaneously with a discord bot in py-cord

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discord.py, python-asyncio, pycord

I cannot run a piece of code asynchronously/simultaneously when the same command is invoked multiple times. Been bothering with this for weeks now, imma go crazy soon...

Here's what happens:
I have this image generation command, which goes to Bing Images to create an image. It uses chrome profiles and selenium to get to the website and provide the image. So far, I've tried FOR WEEKS to make it work, but i still cant get it to work.
I want this to happen:
Someone uses the command:

img a cat
then, the same person, BEFORE the code finishes its first inquiry;
img a dog

I want the program to open a new chrome window and get the images AT THE SAME TIME, and these windows should be able to run simultaneously without interacting with each other.

at the end, the moment an img generation is done in 1 window, it sends it. It does this for all windows, regardless of how many.

I stripped down the code the the main functionality, keep in mind that this code runs in a COG. I need someone to show me how can I make this work. Don't forget that the def there is invoked by the discord bot, and I dont want to be limited by 2 or 3 threads only, i want as many independent windows as the amount of invokes. so if i do >img a [animal here] 100 times, i want it to open 100 windows and do it simultaneously. Below's the code.

```
@bridge.bridge_command(
    name="imagine",
    description="Make pictures with OpenAI's image generation AI: Dall-E!",
    help="Create gorgeous pieces of art using OpenAI's famous Dall-E!",
    aliases=["dall","img","dalle","image"],
)
async def _bing_img(self, ctx: Context, *, prompt: str):
        
    await ctx.defer() 

    windows = os.name in ('nt', 'dos')  
            
    if windows: service = Service('C:\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
    options = Options()
    #options.add_argument('--headless=new')

    if windows: options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop")
    else: options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/ubuntu/botpp/chromeprofiles/")

    options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 4")

    if windows: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    else: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    self.driver = driver

    prompt = ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', prompt) if c <= '\uFFFF')
    self.prompt = prompt

    try:
        driver.get('https://www.bing.com/images/create/')

        search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
        search_box.send_keys(prompt)
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        try:
            wait_for_error = WebDriverWait(driver, 2, ignored_exceptions=self.ignored_exceptions)
            error_text = wait_for_error.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="girer"]/div/div[1]'))).text
            error_msg = self.find_error(error_text)

            if error_msg != None:
                await ctx.send(error_msg)
            
        except:
            wait_for_gen = WebDriverWait(driver, 60, ignored_exceptions=self.ignored_exceptions)

            image = wait_for_gen.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//img[contains(@src, "w=270&h=270")]')))
            images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
            image_links = []
            for image in images:
                src = image.get_attribute('src')
                if src and 'w=270&h=270' in src:
                    src = src.replace('w=270&h=270&c=6&r=0&o=5&', '')
                    image_links.append(src)

            image_links = list(set(image_links)) # Remove duplicates by converting the list to a set and then back to a list...
            driver.close()
            print(image_links)

            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                files = []
                for i in range(len(image_links)):
                    async with session.get(image_links[i]) as resp:
                        img = resp.read()
                        async with io.BytesIO(img) as file:
                            files.append(discord.File(file, "imagine_prax.png"))
                await ctx.send(f"*Your prompt:* `{prompt}`", files=files)            

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("There was an error while generating your image!")
```

Comment: async is not the same as simultaneous. Instead, you should try using multiple threads.